# Strange Garbage Character in SQL server database like ÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃ

Tags: sql-server, php, encoding

I am using HTMLBOX editor for getting Notes/RichText Data input from User. I found there are lot of garbage characters in my database and they keep on doubling on each time user save/update notes.

Below is code sample for my PHP to SQL server connection.

```
<?php
class Model {
    public static $db;

    public static function initialize() {
        self::$db = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server='.DBCONNECTION_SERVER.';Database='.DBCONNECTION_DATABASE.'; Uid='.DBCONNECTION_USER.';Pwd='.DBCONNECTION_PASS.';', null, null,array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_LOWER);
        self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES , false);
    }
}
?>
```

I search for same problem and most of solution suggest to use UTF8 encoding. I set below attribute but no success. :(

```
self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING , PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8);
```

Please see below screenshot. 
[image]

**Update**:

Column Type : NVARCHAR(MAX)

User Input : User can enter or Copy/paste anything. Those garbage character appears when user copy paste from Outlook or other Rich Text Source. The single quote(') from outlook get converted to (Ã¢ÂÂ) garbage character.

Comment: Is the target column nchar/nvarchar?

Comment: Where's the code you're using to actually pass the content to the database? (And no, you don't want UTF8 here, AFAIK.)

Comment: That looks like a Windows 1252 to UTF8 encoding issue http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN page for [PDO::setAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628164.aspx), `PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8` is the default value, so setting it explicitly probably wouldn't change the behavior.

Try the other option, `PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM`, which seems to have worked in this case from the MSDN forums: [Some characters improperly retrieved through PDO driver](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b978309b-ecea-4db9-aad6-426ec8460ec4/some-characters-improperly-retrieved-through-pdo-driver?forum=sqldriverforphp).

Comment: Thanks for help.. But it doesn't work.. I just uploaded screenshot for that.. I added the PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM attribute.. Try to read and updated entire notes.. but doesn't help much..

Comment: @RiteshChandora What is the input data that gets that result? What is the _exact_ data in the table? Use `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), field) FROM table WHERE ID = ??` where `??` is the ID for the row shown in the screenshot. What is the encoding / charset of your PHP page (based on HTML tag and/or headers)? What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: Updated the question. PHP default encoding is utf-8

Comment: @RiteshChandora Ok, and how are you inserting this data into SQL Server? A Dynamic SQL statement executed in the PHP code, or a Stored Procedure called by the PHP code? Please update the question to show exactly how the data is getting into SQL Server.